# JQuery Mobile Red Dot on Tab or button?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I was wondering if anyone know's if you can add ar Red Dot / circle on a footer tab with JQuery Mobile?

See the example image attached.

[image]

Comment: Maybe look into the Count Bubble? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/lists/lists-count.html

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885160/jquerymobile-custom-navigation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

- http://thrivingkings.com/badger/